# ubuntu 18.04 - terminal frozen

Tags: command-line, 18.04

In terminal when I type a commande (`ls` for instance) and press enter, nothing happens.

Only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to work.

Is it a known issue?
How to deal with it?

Comment: Are you talking about `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Hmmm. When I type a command, I get a response so this is not universal behavior. Does this occur on ttys? On your GUI Terminal? On your LiveUSB? Try them all.

Comment: terminal that open when I type ctrl + alt + T. for some reason it works back after reopening the terminal several times.